# how to pass member id from api from one screen to another in react-native

Tags: react-native

react-native

I am Stuck can anyone tell me how to pass member id from API from one screen to another in react-native I have tried certain methods but I am not getting proper solution

Answer (score -1):

You can use [react-native-mmkv](https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-mmkv) or [React Native Async Storage](https://github.com/react-native-async-storage/async-storage) to save your id in memory and load it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).